# Find a space with same homology and fundamental group as a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

I am looking for $X$ which has the same integral homology and fundamental group as the torus, $T$, which is not homotopic equivalent to $T$.
At first, I considered $S^1\vee S^1 \vee S^2$, but $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1 \vee S^2)$ is not $\mathbb Z^2$, so this example doesn't work.

This problem came up in a past qual exam, and so I believe there is a "simple" example, where proving that $X$ is not homotopic equivalent to $T$ is not too "difficult". The argument would probably involve showing that they have distinct cohomology rings.

I would appreciate any help/hint.

Comment: You could use spaces that have trivial homotopy/homology groups, but are not contractible.

Comment: In connection with @J126's comment, you may find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933670/trivial-homology-groups-and-fundamental-group helpful.